# Is there a problem with this For loop in R?

Tags: r

I tried creating a DB that receives data from 7 columns in a spreadsheet using this For loop in R but it's not working.

```
for (n in Base[2:6]){
  a <- Base$Fenabrave
  b <- n
  Dados = data.frame(a=a, b=b)
  RESUMOVEICULO <- as.data.frame(summaryBy(b~a, data=Dados, FUN=c(sum)))
}
```

'a' is creating the column that receives data from the first column in the spreadsheet.
'b' is receiving data from second to sixth columns.
"Dados" is creating the data frame.
"RESUMOVEICULO" is grouping everything together

My end goal is to group all names from the first column and sum the values from all the other columns. Is the loop code correct? If so, how can I fix it?

Here is how the table looks:

[SalesTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MX2DO.png)

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I managed to fix it with this code

```
aa <- BaseTeste2019 %>%
  select(Fenabrave, a, b, c, d, e) %>%
  group_by(Fenabrave) %>%
  summarise(a = sum(a), b = sum(b), c = sum(c), d = sum(d), e = sum(e))
```

It seems the error was caused because the columns were named by numbers, after I replaced them with letters it worked, thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.
In the for loop, are you trying to loop through all the columns or all the rows?
If you are just trying to read an excel file in R, there are specific packages that can help you achieve that.

Comment: Some comments. (1) Looks like your data are already in data frame `Base`, so maybe edit the question title, retrieving from Excel is not the problem? (2) Please provide data as plain text using _e.g._ `dput()` or `head()`, not images. (3) You almost never want to loop through data frames, but use something like the `dplyr` package instead. Answer added based on your end goal.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is convert your data from "wide" (years in columns) to "long" (one column for year, another for sales). Then you can group and sum.

You can use `tidyr::gather()`, `dplyr::group_by()` and `dplyr::summarise()`. Something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Base %>%
  gather(Year, Sales, -Fenabrave) %>%
  group_by(Fenabrave) %>%
  summarise(Total = sum(Sales))
```